# VueJS setup for Atom

Tags: vue.js, ide, vuejs2, atom-editor, text-editor

I was looking for linter and hinter for VueJS. Also i am using tyepsript everywhere so `js-hint` and `linter-jscs` won't be useful.
I currently have these:

- `language-vue`
- `atom-beautify`
- `emmet`
- `linter`
- `linter-ui-default`

The features i need:

- Variable declaration errors
- Semi colon warnings
- Jump to variable description
- If possible Bootstrap-Vue tag completion
- Basic snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic snippets

- https://atom.io/packages/vuejs2-snippets

Linter

- https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint (you should install [eslint-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue) in your project)

Answer (score 2):

To enable Emmet with Vue language on Atom

- Go to keymap.cson on your atom editor (Atom item menu on top)
- Copy and paste this code

  `'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="vue"]:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'`